# Data Storage Direction in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

What would be the best way to store data? Like if my project has `company` and `brand` collection, which one is the best way to store data?:

```
{
   company_name : X,
   brand_id : 1,2  //id's from brand collection
}
```

OR

```
{
   company_name : X
   brand_id : 1
}
{
   company_name : X,
   brand_id : 2 
}
```

Please give some suggestion.

Comment: It depends on what you are going to be doing with the data.

Comment: Read this : [6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)